# Saving temp file in directory in android

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, local-storage, firebase-storage

I have created a temporary file to download another file how to save it in the local storage directory
code-

```
var tempFile = File.createTempFile("file","mp3")
var localFile = File(rootPath,"file","mp3")
```

tempFile is downloaded from firebase storage
how to write it in local File to save it in the internal directory

Comment: Where is it saved now? And what is rootPath? Adapt your code to see.

Comment: var rootPath = File(Environment.getStorageDirectory(),".folder") i want to write the tempFile into localFile it is saved in the storageDirectory

Comment: Put that in your post. Not in a comment. Write a readable post to begin with.